# SQL. Как сделать выборку автора и книг, которые он написал?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select

**Как делать выборку из таблиц многие-ко-многим?**

```
CREATE TABLE books( 
    book_id integer NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
    book_name varchar(32) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE autors( 
    autor_id integer NOT NULL auto_increment primary key, 
    autor_name varchar(32) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE book_autor( 
    book_id integer NOT NULL ,
    autor_id integer  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id , autor_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(book_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (autor_id) REFERENCES autors(autor_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);

Insert into books (book_name) values ('book1'), ('book2'), ('book3'), ('book4');
Insert into autors (autor_name) values ('autor1'), ('autor2'), ('autor3');
Insert into book_autor (book_id, autor_id) values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2);
```

Comment: Два INNER JOIN - чего уж проще...

Comment: @Akina select book_name, autor_name
from books inner join autors on (book_autor.book_id = book_autor.autor_id)
where autor_id = 1 пишу так, что-то не получается)

Comment: Повторяю: ***Два** INNER JOIN*. И используя все три таблицы, само собой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [INNER JOIN](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html)

```
SELECT * FROM books
INNER JOIN book_autor ON books.book_id = book_autor.book_id
INNER JOIN autors ON autors.autor_id = book_autor.autor_id
```